# css in <div> is showing for whole site

Tags: css, html

I have created a table with a div class="exsitingimage" so I can customise the css just for that table, but the css is going on every table in my site. What am I doing wrong? 
  my code:

```
 $wgOut->addHtml('<div class="exsitingimage">');
$wgOut->addHtml('<table><tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Thumbnail</th><th>Dimensions</th><th>User</th><th>Comment</th></tr>'); 
foreach($uploaded as $upload){
$wgOut->addHTML('<tr><td><button data-image-name="' . $upload[0] . '" class="imageSetting">Add</button></td><td>');     
$wgOut->addHTML($upload[0]);
$wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>'); 
$wgOut->addHtml('<img src="images/thumb/'.$upload[0].'/120px-'.$upload[0].'" />'); 
$wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>'); 
$wgOut->addHTML($upload[1]); 
$wgOut->addHTML('x'); 
$wgOut->addHTML($upload[2]); 
$wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>');
$wgOut->addHTML($upload[3]); 
$wgOut->addHtml('</td><td>');
$wgOut->addHtml($upload[4]);
$wgOut->addHtml('</td></tr>'); 
}
$wgOut->addHtml('</table>');
$wgOut->addHtml('</div>');
}
```

In the css file I have:

```
table.exsitingimage     {    border-collapse:collapse;    }
th.exsitingimage     {   border:1px solid #669933;   }  
td.exsitingimage     {padding:8px;    }
```

Comment: If you use `table.exsitingimage` it should only work on `<table>`s with a class `existingimage`. Could you provide a link to your page and post the resulting HTML code instead of PHP?

Comment: The issue here is that the div has the class exsitingimage, therefore table.exsitingimage won't work.

Comment: can you post some html of the other tables that are also getting the exsitingimage class applied

Answer (score 1):

You have the selectors jumbled, switch them around a bit.

Like this

```
.exsitingimage table { border-collapse:collapse; }
.exsitingimage th { border:1px solid #669933; }
.exsitingimage td { padding:8px; }
```

Should work then, but remember as soon as you define another table that is contained within something that has the class `exsitingimage` it'll get that CSS.

Also, in your example the containing DIV has the class of `exsitingimage.`
Either move that down to the table and then you're css will be fine or use my css example.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried <div class="exsitingimage" table> and it messed up the css. My problem isn't that the css isn't working, it is. The table looks great. The problem is that every other table also looks the same, even though I've closed the <div> tag and it doesn't have that class assigned to it. It is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have defined the existingimage class for the table th and td elements, not the div element.

Your HTML should look like:

```
<table class="existingimage">
</table>
```

You don't need the div!

Comment: I moved the class as you said, but why is it wrong to use the <div> I get the same results no? Everything looks the same and the table css is still being used on other tables! I can't work out why it is very frustrating!

Comment: It's not wrong but you don't need it. Also, is the tables that you print on the page getting the class exsitingimage?